# datatable plugin - show and hide more information about a row

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, datatables

datatable plugin - show and hide more information about a row issue :

i want to get that more information by ajax in fnFormatDetails function.but i don't know how do it.i try to put $.ajax in fnFormatDetails function but it seems it have delay to pass the outout to fnOpen function to render new added row ,so the new row is created with empty(undefined) value not the real information.

how can i do that?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "A" in AJAX stands for "asynchronous". When you make an `$.ajax` call, the function returns before the server has responded, hence "asynchronous". The [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function has a success callback that receives the server's response, that callback has to do all the work of processing the server's response and updating your page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/where/ever',
    data: data_for_the_url,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        /*
         * This is where you use `data` to update the page.
         * $.ajax will call this function when the server
         * has successfully responded.
         */
    }
});
/*
 * When you get here, the server still hasn't responded so you can't
 * update your page yet.
 */
```

So, put all your page updating logic inside the `success` callback function.